# How do I refer to methods in AppDelegate.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have a view controller called "Home" and I want to call one of its methods, which is called `myFunction()`.

```
let home = Home() as! UIViewController
home.myFunction()
```

This doesn't seem to work. Why?

Comment: May you please help me instead of down voting my question? Thanks!

Comment: IMO it is not a good question. It is quite lengthy and not 100% clear what your intention is. And then also "But hey, I got no luck!", that is absolutely superfluous. Programming has nothing to do with luck.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I appreciate it. I tried to be as precise and concise as possible, but I'll do my best to edit the question.

Comment: Maybe as hint: IMO the screenshot is not needed. Make clear, why you want to call `animateStuff` from this place, because to me it seems that it is not a good design approach, but since it is not clear, nobody has the full picture.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer following your feedback. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Home is your `rootViewController` then you can call the `animateStuff` method from your AppDelegate methods by doing so:

```
if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController? as? Home {
    viewController.animateStuff()
}
```

If `Home` is not your `rootViewContoller`, then you have to check if `presentedView` controller is `Home` then call its methods:

```
if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController.presentedViewController as? Home {
    viewController.animateStuff()
}
```

And finally it looks like that your animateStuff method should first set buttons transform to its initial state

```
func animateStuff(){
    let optionsAnimateStuff = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
    self.buttonPlay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 3.0, options:
        optionsAnimateStuff, animations: {
            self.buttonPlay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.13, 1.13)
        }, completion: { finished in
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I am sure your code works fine but whenever I quit the app (please note that I don't close it, I just go to the Home screen) and the reopen it again the animation doesn't begin. Have you got any ideas? Also should't it be `Home.animateStuff()` instead of `viewController.animateStuff()`? Thank you so much!

Comment: No it should not be Home.animateStuff(). In order to make it work you will need to use above code inside applicationDidBecomeActive function of your appdelegate and not inside application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Here's what my AppDelegate file looks like: http://pastebin.com/0GJ1d9he. Thank you!

Comment: Can you check whether any of ifs condition is met by println different message inside them

Comment: I run the app. Both "test 1" and "test2" messages are showed in the console's output. I close the app and open it again (whiteout closing it using the multitasking feature) and "test1" and "test2" appear again. This is weird! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error though. Please check this screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/yaI9gWe.png. I get a "UIViewController? does not have a member named presentedViewController".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69233/discussion-between-zellb-and-cecexx).